# how to manage page size and margin in crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and using crystal report with .Net (WinForm / Visual Studio 2010).

I was thinking what would be the way to setup page size and top, bottom, left and right margins in report. I tried to look options but couldn't get it. Please guide me.

Comment: which tool u use for editing crystal report? VS2010 or Crystal Reports ??

Answer (score 18):

If you use **Crystal Reports** to design your report, Page size and Margins can be edited by Page Setup. **Right Click** on your report select **Page Setup**. You'll get a window as shown below. 
[image: Page Setup in Crystal Report]

Here you can edit the page size and margins...

If you use **VS2010** to design your report, follow the below steps

[image: Printer Setup]
[image]
For Margins Open Page Setup 
[image]

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Good answer; 'no printer' is suggested, anyway.

Comment: Thx but i cant get what u say as 'no printer'

Comment: Look at 'Print Setup' image; RICOH printer params are nested into the report, but final user won't have RICOH printe. So flag 'no printer' to increase report performance

Comment: 'Therefore, as a best practice for scalability, modify your report to use no printer driver.' read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225523(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: yeah got it now ! Thq very mcuh

Comment: @EmanueleGreco how do you then set the size of the paper, and what papersize does crystal report defaults to the the Noprinter option

Answer (score 8):

And to change them programmatically:

```
        yourReportObject.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4;
        yourReportObject.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));
```