# Crystal report page size asp.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have web application in which i am using crystal report,problem is that whenever i add new report to my project it comes with fixed width ,size,and i can not resize it.I tried many setting but it remain fixed size,just take look on image of report fixed size.Every new report comes with fixed size.what to do?

[image]

Comment: set Size as A4 in page setup. Have you tried this?

Comment: This [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360581/how-to-mange-page-size-and-margin-in-crystal-report/12365035#12365035) may help you !! Try this and get back with results...

Comment: @HariharanAnbazhagan that link helped me. Please enter it as an answer so that i can mark it as an answer

Comment: Thats fine, you can upvote that answer if it helps you. Do you think reproducing answer will be good?...