# Having issue with Crystal Report Sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I am learning Crystal Reporting and facing a very weird problem. 
This is the design of `Crystal Report` 
[image]

This report works absolutely fine **BUT** as soon as I put more fields in my `Report Footer`, `Page Footer`section or even when I expand these Sections, data present in `Report` and `Page Footer` disappears.

[image]

What's the issue. Is it that I can't accommodate so many fields in these sections or is it something that I'm missing

Comment: Sum of heights of `Page Header` and `Details` and `Page Footer` should be less than height of your page ;).

Comment: Sir my how can I accommodate all of my data? I mean I know my size is exceeding but what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sum of heights of your sections like `Page Header`, `Details` and `Page Footer` is greater than the height of your page, last section will suppress in the preview.

You can change size of your page by following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12360581/4519059).