# WPF Crystal Reports Viewer: Check if report is in landscape format

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

Does anyone know how i can check if a crystal report is in landscape format?

Checking the actual height and width of the cr wpf control doesn't give me correct values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> File -> Page Setup -( there is all page related setting include margin and oriantation.)

Check this link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/crystal_reports_page_layout.htm

[how to manage page size and margin in crystal report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360581/how-to-manage-page-size-and-margin-in-crystal-report)

**Updated**
Before change via WPF via code, you must check in preview that your report will properly fit in your desired orientation.

to change dynamically , you just access crystal report object, in which there are property to give information.

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printersettings = new   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
printersettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pageSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
...
pageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("name", 400, 600);
rp.PrintToPrinter(printersettings, pageSettings, false)
```

Check this links -  [Crystal Reports prints portrait orientation instead of landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800187/crystal-reports-prints-portrait-orientation-instead-of-landscape)

Comment: I mean of course programmatically with wpf, as I noted in the headline

Comment: in your solution you set the orientation... i just want to know the orientation which is set in the rpt

Comment: that you already set while report design. why you need at programme side, if you need to change, then create 2 report for both oriantation and call based on your requiements

Comment: i'm wirting an application which loads and shows reports, i don't create them by myself. i need to know the orientation for zooming in the ui...

Comment: fine, by this line "if ( rp.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation == PaperOrientation.Landscape) { do your work} else { do your work}" , you can check.